# Deep Learning ROC and Average Precision Curve Results

Tags: deep-learning, classification, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I used Vgg16 to create a deep learning model and the dataset is imbalanced so, I used class_weight argument in fit_generator method.

The model result as the following:
accuracy= 98.9% and loss= 0.1731

And I got the following ROC and Average Precision curves:

[image]
[image]

Why I got these results?
Is there any problem in ROC and average precision?